# Assembly language loops issue - random integers also printing

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having a problem with my loop, in a way, it is working as it should; as you can see in the image below the program is printing the numbers of each user input and followed by the correct characters in order of user input. However, I am also getting random numbers appearing in between them.

[image: output]

```
    mov esi, [items]            //Esi points to the first item - Calling data from the C code and assigning it to the esi source indexer, in this case being the users inputted number. 



    loop1: mov eax, [esi]       // moves the first number which is in esi to the eax register
           push eax             // pushes it onto the stack so it can be used 
           call printInt        // Prints the integer in the eax register



           push ','             // Prints a comma after the number inputted
           call printChar

           push ' '             // Prints a space
           call printChar

           push '*'
           call printChar

           call printNewLine

           mov eax, [esi]
           inc esi          // Now that's odd. Esi is pointing at an integer, and that's 4 bytes in size.
           cmp eax, 0

           jnz loop1



        jmp finish          // We need to jump past the subroutine(s) that follow
                                // else the CPU will just carry on going.
```

Any help would be really appreciated here! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with "c" when it's assembly? Is this inline in a C program?

Comment: Yes it is, the input and output of the program are handled with C, which has been provided by my lecturer.

Comment: This is indeed an odd loop. It's looping through the single bytes pointed to by ESI, stopping when is sees a byte of 0--what you'd expect from printing a string. But then it grabs four bytes at a time--overlapping--and prints them as an integer, then the commas and such. Very strange.

Comment: You seem to have already spotted the bug yourself! `// Now that's odd. Esi is pointing at an integer, and that's 4 bytes in size.`

Comment: That was a comment made by my lecturer, I couldn't quite make sense of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you are reading from is just a continous memory block, that starts at some address. In your case, the adress is given as 32-bit  value obtained by dereferencing of `items` label:

```
mov esi, [items] // So now we hold the address of an array
```

The array contains four 32-bit wide integers. As your CPU has little-endian byte ordering, memory content of the array can be written as:

```
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Now, when you are trying to print a specific element, you need to know, that assembly language does not facilite any sort of pointer arithmetic (like in C) - you need to handle it by yourself.

Let's take a view of what happens when you call `printInt` at first and second time. At first, you are getting proper result, because the adress points to first element, that is:

```
01 00 00 00
```

However, as you increment `%esi` merely by one, the second element is read as:

```
00 00 00 02
```

which represents value of `2 * 2*24 = 33554432`.

In order to fix the code, you need to take into account the size of each element, that is four bytes. For example, you might replace `inc` instruction with:

```
add esi, 4
```

Comment: Could just scale _ESI_ with `[ESI*4]` .

Comment: Thank you that worked :) and thank you for explaining it so well.